# Realm complains 'Binary too big'

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, realm, nsdata

I want to save image in Realm but it says that binary is too big. I know that NSData should be less than 16MB. So how can I handle this issue? Anyway to resize NSData?

Comment: The recommended way is to save the image file path instead of the actual image

Comment: It's an image? Do you want to save it "full size" and "full quality", and then maybe do a piece by piece? Or do you want to resize it?

Comment: I want to save full quality

Comment: Have you considered using `NSURLCache` to store images?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem as well, doing research I fixed my error with help from Realm docs. Here is the link. https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/scanner/#overview.

The helpful code snippet:

```
 func data() -> Data {
 var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) 
// Resize the image if it exceeds the 2MB API limit
 if (imageData?.count)! > 2097152 {
   let oldSize = self.size
   let newSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: oldSize.height / oldSize.width * 
 800)
   let newImage = self.resizeImage(self, size: newSize)
   imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.7)
   }
   return imageData!
 }
```

To add to Realm, A code can be something like this:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var thumbImg: UIImageView!
     let picture = Image()
     let imageDownSizing = thumbImg.image?.data()

     //thumbImg.image is of type UIImage type, so convert UIImage -> Data. 
     //picture.image is of type Data. 
     picture.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbImg.image!)
     picture.image = imageDownSizing

     let item = Item()
     item.toImage = picture

       do{
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(item)
            }
        }catch{
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference parts of the file with `NSFileHandle` and it's `offsetInFile` method. e.g. in 16MB chunks.

Comment: I have an idea to store image path url as String and then use that url. Is it ok?

Comment: generally speaking one rarely stores an entire image inside a database.. But that'd be a surefire way to sort the problem out.

Comment: Offtop: Is it possible to save UIColor in Realm?

Comment: Probably as a transformed property if anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
which will get your image in Data format and compress the size